# Using __init__ to create a class for four vectors

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, initialization

[image: Four Vectors]

```
import numpy as np
class FourVector:
""" This document is a demonstration of how to create a class of Four vector """
    def __init__(self,ct=0,x=0,y=0,z=0):
        self.a=(ct,x,y,z)
        self.r=(ct,r=[x,y,z])

P0 = FourVector()
print P0.a

P1 = FourVector(ct=9,x=1,y=2,z=4)
print P1.a

P2 = FourVector(ct=99.9,r=[1,2,4])
```

My code is working fine for `P0`, `P1` but doesn't work for `P2` :( Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile. What do you expect `self.r=(ct,r=[x,y,z])` to do?

Comment: As for P2, what do you expect passing an `r` argument to the constructor to do when your constructor doesn't take an argument with that name?

Comment: To user: Arihh, yes you are right.
To Bi Rico: Numpy array

Comment: Please, avoid posting text as an image; next time, do a copy & paste of the text instead of providing a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a `r` parameter in your `__init__` method:

```
class FourVector:
    def __init__(self, ct = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, r = None):
        self.a = (ct, x, y, z)
        if r is not None:
            self.a = (ct, r[0], r[1], r[2])

P0 = FourVector()
print P0.a

P1 = FourVector(ct = 9, x = 1, y = 2, z = 4)
print P1.a

P2 = FourVector(ct = 99.9, r = [1, 2, 4])
print P2.a
```

Comment: I was struggling to create another layer... " like what you did above, by stating r!=[]
Flexibly using if statement,
I'm a true newbie in programming, just need more practice!

Comment: `if r != []` means "if you passed a parameter `r` to `__init__`"

Comment: Note that this isn't a correct solution to the assignment. The space components are supposed to be stored in a numpy array. Also, it's a bad idea to have a mutable default argument, even if you don't happen to mutate it. That said, this solves the immediate bug.

Comment: Instead of `r = []` and `if r != []:`, I recommend `r = None` and `if r is not None:`.  See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`r` isn't even in the argument list, why? Just add it:

```
def __init__(self,ct=0,x=0,y=0,z=0, r=None)
```

Comment: :) but OP probably doesn't yet :P

Comment: No, i don't feel a need to mention it, since `__init__` is a special method that will be called  only once, when the class is instantiated.

Comment: @aIKid: Wrong. `__init__` will be called to instantiate each instance, and each instance will share the same default list for `r`. This kind of thing is why you don't use a mutable default argument, even if you think it should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

class FourVector:
""" This document is a demonstration of how to create a class of Four vector """
    def __init__(self, ct=0, x=0, y=0, z=0, r=[]):
        self.ct = ct
        self.r =  np.array(r if r else [x,y,z])


P0 = FourVector()
print P0.r

P1 = FourVector(ct = 9, x = 1, y = 2, z = 4)
print P1.r

P2 = FourVector(ct = 99.9, r = [1, 2, 4])
print P2.r
```

Comment: It's probably better to use `None` for the default argument `r`, so you don't accidentally modify the list and get weird bugs.

Comment: This is what @user2357112 is referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/1730674

Comment: \@askewchan Don't we avoid this issue since 'r' is defined on class initialization? I may be missing something, and all else equal, using r=None in the code I provided works just fine, and if there's a non-zero chance to create bugs due to something unknown to me, I'll start using None defaults. Thanks.